# Do such field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}_p$ exists?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}_p$ be the p-adic complex field and    $ \{a_i\}\subseteq \mathbb{C}_p$ be a finite set, then do there exist a field automorphism  $\phi:\mathbb{C}_p\to\mathbb{C}_p$ such that for all $i$ we have $\phi(a_i)\in \mathbb{\bar{Q}_p}$?

I guess Zorn's lemma might be helpful.

Comment: Choose an ordering such that $\Bbb{Q}(a_1,\ldots,a_m)/\Bbb{Q}$ is purely transcendental of degree $m$ and the remaining $a_i$ are algebraic over it. Choose $b_1,\ldots,b_m \in \Bbb{Q}_p$ such that $\Bbb{Q}(a_1,\ldots,a_m,b_1,\ldots,b_m)/\Bbb{Q}$ is purely transcendental of degree $2m$. Then $a_l \mapsto b_l, b_l \mapsto a_l$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb{Q}(a_1,\ldots,a_m,b_1,\ldots,b_m)$, it extends to an automorphism of the larger field $\Bbb{C}_p$, and the image of the $a_i, i > m$ are in $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks! It is helpful!